# Returning a list of output parameters from an Oracle Stored Procedure using JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, jooq

As output of an Oracle stored procedure, I want to return a list of ids as output parameter back to my Java code using JOOQ. The number of id elements can vary. How can I do this using JOOQ and how should the PL/SQL procedure be coded to accomplish this.

Comment: This seems to be a related topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60342/how-to-answer-do-my-work-for-me-questions

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to return sets / tables / arrays / cursors in Oracle. I'd personally prefer the following although all the other approaches are equally supported by jOOQ:

```sql
CREATE TYPE ids AS TABLE OF NUMBER(18);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ids RETURN ids IS 
  v_result ids;
BEGIN
  SELECT CAST(COLLECT(id) AS ids)
  INTO v_result
  FROM t_book;

  RETURN v_result;
END get_ids;
/
```

The relevant generated jOOQ classes are now similar to these:

```java
public class GetIds extends AbstractRoutine<IdsRecord> {
    // ...
}

public class IdsRecord extends ArrayRecordImpl<Long> {
    // ...
}

public class Routines {

    // For standalone calls
    public static IdsRecord getIds(Configuration configuration) {
    }

    // For embedded calls
    public static Field<IdsRecord> getIds() {
    }
}
```

You can now either use the standalone call as such:

```java
Routines.getIds(configuration).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This yields the number values directly

```
1
2
3
4
```

Or, you embed the function using the [`DSL.table()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Field-) operator

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(table(Routines.getIds()))
   .fetch()
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This yields individual records

```
+------------+
|COLUMN_VALUE|
+------------+
|           1|
+------------+
+------------+
|COLUMN_VALUE|
+------------+
|           2|
+------------+
+------------+
|COLUMN_VALUE|
+------------+
|           3|
+------------+
+------------+
|COLUMN_VALUE|
+------------+
|           4|
+------------+
```